# AJAX get request JSONP parsererror: readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load"}]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey Im currently attempting to make multiple ajax request calls using the deferred when and done functions. However, on some of the requests I am getting parse-error: readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"load".

I've tried to look at other questions similar to my question and have tried debugging in all ways, but have fallen short.

Here is my ajax request call:

```
    $.ajax({
      'url' : message.action,
      'data' : parameterMap,
      'dataType' : 'jsonp',
      'async' : 'true',
      'jsonpCallback' : 'cb',
      'cache': true
    })
    .done(function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("Success: " + textStatus);

      //inserting data to map
      var mapIndex = i.toString();
      yelpResults = yelpResults.set(mapIndex, JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
    }) //end of done
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error[' + errorThrown + '], status[' + textStatus + '], jqXHR[]');
    })

  );
```

That ajax request is being pushed into a list, where that list is returned and used within this function:

```
var generateBusiness = function(term,subPointResults){
  var promises = yelpSearch(term, subPointResults);
  console.log("Generate business is being called");
  $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
    // call
    console.log("All requests done");
    // findPriorityResuts(subPointResults);
    yelpRequestCounter = 0;
  });
}
```

Im making a 10 total requests where about 5 does successfully load and the others fail with the parse error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! :)

EDIT: I had this working, in terms of each request being successfully parsed, but I was calling each request on an interval of 1 second. and wanted to find a different, parallel way of doing it.

So I know its not the data thats coming in.

Thanks!

Comment: `on some of the requests I am getting parse-error` - perhaps the JSONP is invalid

Comment: `i know that some of the jsonp is not invalid` - it should ALL be valid

Comment: but as pointed out by a now removed comment .. `JSON.stringify(jqXHR)` looks odd, is that definitely correct?

Comment: If you are doing jsonp calls in a loop, the callback needs to be different....

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah i meant to say all jsonp data i got was valid. sorry

Comment: @JaromandaX i initially had it as just data and was trying out jqXHR and parsing that and both ways doesnt make a difference

Comment: @epascarello could you elaborate please? 
my goal is to have one ajax request that i call x amount of times. and that was the reason why i looped it, so that i could push it into an array where i then use the apply method to call each method within the array, hoping that i can make multiple ajax calls in parallel

Comment: not realizing that jsonp is actually a script request, not an ajax request, which is why each callback needs to be different. Let jQuery set it internally unless api requires a specific configuration for it. If so would need to make these all sequential requests

Comment: @charlietfl ah i didnt know that. would you mind providing an example of how i would let jQuery set it internally ? and im using yelp's api, which doesnt support CORS

Comment: just remove the `jsonpCallback` option and it will be done internally by `$.ajax` automatically...see docs

Comment: @charlietfl you are my hero. Ive been struggling with this issue for about 2 weeks and it was so simple. thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jsonp requests are actually script requests, not ajax requests, using the same callback for multiple requests is not good.

Remove `'jsonpCallback' : 'cb'` and let jQuery dynamically create, and  importantly, track unique callbacks